# Flux: How to prevent element processing when some element has concrete value?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The following test method:

```
@Test
void testMe() {
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .map(this::saveInDb)
            .toStream().count();
}

int saveInDb(int element) {
    System.out.println(element + " successfully stored in DB.");
    return element;
}
```

prints always:

```
1 successfully stored in DB.
2 successfully stored in DB.
3 successfully stored in DB.
4 successfully stored in DB.
5 successfully stored in DB.
```

**The question that I have:** how to prevent any saving to DB when some particular element available in the Flux?

*For example*: I do not want to store anything to DB when element `5` exists in Flux.

Is it even possible to implement this requirement in a non-blocking fashion?

Comment: you can either filter https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate- or just have an `if-statement` in your `map` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if you can fit the whole `Flux` into memory:

```java
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .collectList()
    .filter(items -> !items.contains(5))
    .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
    .map(this::saveInDb)
```

If the Flux can't fit into the memory you can:

- buffer the `Flux` and check the presence only in the buffered subsets (this might not be right for your use case)
- consume the `Flux` twice, first check the presence with a filter, if the item was not present then subscribe again (this obviously only works if the `Flux` is guaranteed to have the same output on both occasions)

Comment: you dont need to `collectList` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, may I ask you to provide an example?

Comment: an example? you just filter the flux, and then map. Why the collectList, and flatMapIterable?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I think the original use case was to do ZERO processing if any element in the `Flux` matches the "predicate". `map`+`filter` can only prevent processing of  _particular_ elements (the ones that don't match the filter)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [takeUntil](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntil-java.util.function.Predicate-) or [takeWhile](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Also throwing dedicated exception with `onErrorComplete` might be an option:

```
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .map(val -> {
      if (val.equals(5)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stopping flux");
      }
      return val;
    })
    .map(this::saveInDb)
    .onErrorComplete(RuntimeException.class)
    .toStream()
    .count();
```

Just replace RuntimeException to something more specific.